# Toggling CSS display for screen but not print media

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this html: `<div id="zoom">...</div>`. I have it set to "display:none" when the page is loaded. When a certain event is fired, the "zoom" id is set to "display:block". However, I want is so that if the user prints the page, even after that particular event is fired, it will never print the stuff in the "zoom" id. The event sets it to block via jQuery:

```
$("#zoom").css({"display":"block"});
```

Is there a way to define, in jQuery that it should be applied to the screen media only? The above code sets it across all media types.

Comment: Have you tried using the print media query?  Seems like what you would use in this situation, but from the wording in your post it sounds like you're already familiar with media queries.

Comment: you could make a print button, that, when clicked, hides or removes entirely the div

Comment: I believe the only full-proof method is like the posted link. A print button can be ignored and any JS is essentially going to add styles inline and thus persist when printing as printing would use the current DOM layout. I'm not totally sure if something like `!important` in the CSS would override the inline styles, but possibly. Using `!important` would have other issues as well. So if used sparingly and it works go there, but I wouldn't want important all over my CSS as it would be difficult to then override things.

Comment: @Leeish  `!important` does override inline styles as long as those inline styles are not also specified as `!important`

Comment: I see that below. I'd still stray from using !important unless it's just for a few things. But I guess if the `!important` is really only in the print media type, that would be manageable. Better than another js lib just for that.

Comment: @Leeish agreed.  `!important` is always a last resort, but this is one of the few cases it's useful.  It does exactly what it was intended to, namely to override a style with a higher specificity due to cascading order.

Comment: Agreed. and I actually appreciate it, because I've come across this in the past and thought it a headache for doing print styles and it never dawned on me to use `!important`. I'm stashing this one away as a use case I hadn't thought of before. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you should be able to just use a media query for print.  The only odd addition is that you will probably have to use the `!important` rule because the element is made visible using javascript (presumably inline styles).

```
@media print {
  #zoom {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: You aren't misunderstanding anything. The only issue was my lack of understanding what !important was all about. That's all that was needed.